# How to display in xsl:value-of with a javascript return value function?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I'd google for answer but to no avail, there's example but don't work.

I have an xsl but I need to include javascript functions and possible updating it on the fly. But I'm stuck at the very basic or displaying xsl:value-of with a javascript funciton that returns a value.

I'd just started on xslt for a few days and had tried msxsl and a few other solution, but I can't get it to work.

Below is my testing code, appreciate if anyone could help me out with solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
                exclude-result-prefixes="php"
                xsl:extension-element-prefixes="php">

<xsl:template match="data">

<head>
<title>test woe</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function retValue()
     {
          var val = 1;
          return val;
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>
     <xsl:value-of select="retValue()"/>
</body>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT is not about executing javascript. It's definitely possible to use extension functions in ECMAScript but that's a different story.

Comment: @Alex, let's say i have XSLT page and it have a set of names/attributevalues to be displayed and also some buttons that will affect the display values, can it be done using XSLT or there is certain ways to achieve that sort of result?

Answer (score -1):

Even I had similar problem. This doesnt work anyways. You may be able to  do it using msxsl. u will get example from net.

Instead what you can do is call an onload javascript function and assign the value there.
something like
d= document.getElementByID('div') ;
d.innerHTML ="the value";